# dynamic variable ng-repeat inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have ng-repeat inside other ng-repeat directive. 
I'm trying to make second ng-repeat dynamic, using key from the first one, but this syntax doesnt work. Is there a way to make it work? Different notation maybe?

```
<div class="entry" ng-repeat="(key, choice) in choices">
    <div >
        <div ng-repeat="option in fields['user_' + key].options | filter : {v:choices[key].junior.v}" class="box-content-value">{{option.l}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Filter works without problems, because it's an object, `fields.user_$` on the other hand is not, and I have to combine string + variable to make it work.

Request in comment- choices is not relevant, and is just plain array of js objects

fields on the other hand look like this

```
"fields": {
    "user_0": {
        "display": true,
        "options": [{
            "k": 0,
            "v": "",
            "l": "Please select"
        }, {
            "k": 1,
            "v": "male",
            "l": "Male"
        }, {
            "k": 2,
            "v": "female",
            "l": "Female"
        }],
        "read_only": false
    }
}
```

So i have to display `fields.options.l` full value having only its `fields.option.v` property. Thats why i use filter here.

Comment: what is `choices`? what is `fields`? can you provide sample? also you can use `choice` instead of `choices[key]`. What you mean _but this syntax doesnt work._? you have error? or something else?

Comment: Can you give us your model values? Kind of hard to understand how you are wanting to manipulate your data

Comment: fields['user_' + key] is the problem. Angular doesnt combine this string pointer with key variable

Comment: <div ng-repeat="option in fields.options | filter : {.....

Comment: `fields` is an array not object, you need another `ng-repeat` for the options after repeating the fields

Comment: can you also provide sample for `choices`?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up these objects. I forgot I'm rebuilding it somewhere in the process. But MoLow already answered my question. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Animal, so `fields` is array, or object? if this object you should fix your post, because otherwise provided answer not work

Comment: Yes, it's an object. I already fixed the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$index` instead of `key`:

```
<div class="entry" ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <div >
        <div ng-repeat="option in fields['user_' + $index].options | filter : {v:choice.junior.v}" class="box-content-value">{{option.l}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this not work, because `fields` is array, and array have not property like this `'user_0'`